# Ошибка CS0012 Тип "Form" определен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

Не понимаю как решить проблему. Я начал изучать юнит-тесты. У меня проект с виндовс форм. Я создал проект тестирования и хочу в этом проекте из формы выполнить паблик метод, но на методе ошибка:
Ошибка  CS0012  Тип "Form" определен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
Я делал ссылку на проект.

```
Form1.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab7_FileSystem
{
...
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
...
        public string CorrectPath(string folderFullName)
        {
            DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(folderFullName);
            return theFolder.FullName;
        }
...
    }
```

```
UnitTest1.cs

using Lab7_FileSystem;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace FSTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.CorrectPath(""); //Подчеркивается "CorrectPath"
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: На ошибку наведите, там будет желтая лампа, жмете, самым первым должно быть что-то по типу "добавить ссылку на проект", жмете, студия сделает все за вас. Ну а если хотите решить сами, то в списке проектов ищете тот, где тесты, ищете там "Зависимости", жмете ПКМ - "Добавить ссылку на проект", галку ставите на основной проект, ок. Ну а вообще, формы не тестируют, тестируют логику, которая отдельно лежит в собственном классе, а сейчас у вас просто форма выполняет не свою задачу, она должна просто вывести на экран данные, все.

Comment: Дело в том что я так делал, ссылка на проект добавлена, но все равно почему-то такая ошибка выскакивает

Comment: студия иногда тупит, попробуйте вручную убрать и заново добавить ссылку на проект

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема, при такой ошибке нужно сделать связь сборки с System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0 как это пишется в рекомендации, но почему-то в моем nunit нет пункта "Сборка", поэтому негде связывать. Приходится отдельно функции копировать и подстраивать под тест